# Nvidia drivers on debian

Tags: debian, nvidia, gpu, x

I'm on an ASUS laptop, with the following GPUs

```
$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 5917 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1d10 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 drivers: modesetting,nvidia,nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz
           GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A Direct Rendering: N/A
```

I installed to nvidia driver using the `.run` script from their website and this works:

```
$ nvidia-smi                                                                        139
Mon Apr  8 08:08:14 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   41C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also tried installing the drivers via apt, which didn't yield any satisfying results, so I prefer to stick to the script installed driver.

However, I some things broke after that. For instance, running `blender` crashes:

```
$  blender
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
/build/blender-vcDKFu/blender-2.79.b+dfsg0/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:198: X11 glXQueryVersion() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
[1]    12703 segmentation fault  blender
```

Most tips online were "run `nvidia-xconfig`" or "`install libgl`", but
1) I can't install anything from apt that touches nvidia, because it wants me to remove the driver installed via the `run` script
2) I don't want to use the discrete GPU for `xorg`

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Can you provide output of this? `lspci | grep NVIDIA`

Comment: May be wrong, but the third line of blender output about jack server may be associated with sound drivers. Do you have working sound in your system?

Comment: `~> lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d10 (rev ff)`
I have a working sound system (on pulseaudio)